# Can I copy a tag wiki from another SE site?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am in the process of writing a tag wiki for a tag over on [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). Because that particular concept is also relevant to Chemistry, an identical tag exists here. I anticipate that the excerpts will ultimately diverge from each other to include information relevant to the two fields. But for my initial seeding of the wikis, is it generally acceptable to simply copy and paste the same text?

As the putative copyright holder, I wouldn't object to someone else copying the text over to a tag wiki for another SE site. And my understanding is that by writing the one tag wiki, I am granting a license to SE that explicitly allows it to be copied to another tag wiki. Is this correct?

Comment: Customize it for Chem and note that it was based on/taken from Phys.SE, I think.

Answer (score 9):

**It should be fine to reuse a tag wiki across sites** (customized as needed to accommodate the subject).

All user-contributed content is licensed under a [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for reuse… but that license also requires proper attribution. But as a pragmatic matter, there a point where text becomes purely instructional, and it's not always practical to attribute every bit of text ever suggested here back to the original author. I'm not sure if this is literally covered under "Fair Use", but if someone wants to assert their rights as Licensor, I'm sure we can accommodate them by replacing that text with something a bit more within the spirit of shared community governance.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Roberts answer I would like to expand this a little.

On the very bottom of every site it is stated

> user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

If you follow the attribution required you will get to a list, what you should be doing:

> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Now for wiki entries, numbers 3 & 4  is honestly a little bit complicated, as usually it is not at all obvious (you will have to dive into the history).

I therefore think it should be sufficient if you just include the full URL to the tag-wiki entry.